# Jackson JSON Filter without @JsonFilter Annotation

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm trying to filter the response of an API Endpoint using the Jackson library.

I can use @JsonFilter("[filterNameHere]") but this ends up with the class expecting the filter to be applied every time.

Is there a way I can filter the response only on one particular instance?

```
Pizza pizza = pizzaService.getPizzaById(pizzaId);

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("baseFilter", SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.serializeAllExcept("base"));

String json = mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(pizza);

return Response.status(200).entity(json).build();
```

I've tried looking around but haven't been able to find anything right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately association between filter id and class is static, so any class either has it or does not; that is, you can not sometimes have a filter, other times not.

It should be however possible to either:

- indicate a "default" filter to use (with `SimpleFilterProvider.setDefaultFilter()`), to be used in case there is no explicitly registered filter matching the id. This filter could basically be "include all" filter, which would have no effect on processing.
- indicate that in case no match is found for filter id, no filtering is done: `SimpleFilterProvider.setFailOnUnknownId(false)` (on provider instance)

So I think what you really want to do is second option, something like:

```
SimpleFilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider();
filters.setFailOnUnknownId(false);
String json = mapper.writer(filters).writeValueAsString(pizza);
```

Comment: A different solution using MixIns is shown in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44673223/7796663