# Jackson: How to set alias for properties dynamically

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson2

I know that Jackson supported Mixin and I can set alias for properties like following:

```
public final class Rectangle {
    private int w;

    public Rectangle(int w) {
       this.w = w;
    }

    public int getW() { return w; }
    }
}

abstract class MixIn {
  MixIn(@JsonProperty("width") int w) { }

  @JsonProperty("width") abstract int getW();
}
```

and do this:

```
objectMapper.addMixInAnnotations(Rectangle.class, MixIn.class);
```

but I don't want to do it with annotations. I want to add aliases dynamically for example like this:

```
objectMapper.addAlias(Rectangle.class, "w", "width")
```

Is there are any way to do this?

Note: Also acceptable the solution like  [excluding properties dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671154/jackson-filtering-out-fields-without-annotations/46391108#46391108)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with a custom `AnnotationIntrospector`, where you can intercept and modify Jackson detection and use of `@JsonProperty` (even if the field/method is not annotated)

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyName;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.Annotated;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector;

public class DynamicPropertyAliasIntrospector extends JacksonAnnotationIntrospector
{
    @Override
    public PropertyName findNameForSerialization(Annotated a)
    {
        // if get method has @JsonProperty, return that
        PropertyName pn = super.findNameForSerialization(a);
        if (a.hasAnnotation(JsonProperty.class)) {
            return pn;
        }
        // if not annotated, value may be set dynamically 
        if (a.getName().equals("getW")) {
            // value may be set from external source as well (properties file, etc)
            pn = new PropertyName("width");
        }
        return pn;
    }
}
```

usage: pass an instance of the custom annotation introspector to the object mapper:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new DynamicPropertyAliasIntrospector());
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(3);
    try {
        mapper.writeValue(System.out, r);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

output:

```
{"width":3}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer I will check and let you know.

Comment: how did it go??

Comment: In your example there is no way to check a class for add alias. In your case all methods which defined as 'getW' will be mapped as 'weight' and it doesn't matter is it method of `Rectangle` or not.

Comment: the solution is where I pointed to: Jackson's `AnnotationIntrospector`. take a deeper look into it (it is open source after all) there are many methods that can be overriden.