# Is there a way to ignore jackson fields at runtime without using @JsonIgnore

Tags: java, hibernate, java-8, jackson

I'm trying to serialize an object and at runtime choose the fields to be ignored without using @JsonIgnore annotation, I'm trying the follow code:

```
            @Override
            protected boolean _isIgnorable(Annotated a) {
                if (a.getName().contains("foo")) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        });
```

but this code doesn't work because I cant get the fields, anyone can help me?

Comment: why do you not want to use @JsonIgnore?

Comment: Hope this helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44671154/jackson-filtering-out-fields-without-annotations

Comment: @rhowell this is a legacy software and I can't change the architecture I was trying to choose the fields inside this method at runtime

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, what your implementation of AnnotationIntrospector used?

Put breakpoint on `if (a.getName().contains("foo")) {` line.

And inside `_isIgnorable` of `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector` class

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngdqx.png)